# Is there any better way to do this (html/css/js)? Bubbles scattered around the page, some with content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's my pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pdBzQm

I want these bubbles to be scattered around the page. Some of them will have content, some not. I'm not so good with html/css and I was wondering if there is any better way to accomplish this so this is somewhat responsive. The size of the circles does not have to shrink now. I will use media queries to adjust to different viewports. My concern is the html/css code.

Here's the css code:

```
body {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Glacial Indifference';
        color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Comment: Are you using a css preprocessor? I think sass has a `random` function that may be useful

Comment: I would opt for js .. for both drawing and scattering

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any JS.